# What is the SOLR plugin for Liferay meant for?

Tags: apache, tomcat, solr, lucene, liferay

I am using Liferay 6.1 and I am trying to learn how to incorporate search functionality into Liferay Portal. I was able to run Apache SOLR inside Liferay's tomcat container but I don't understand what the solr plugin for liferay is meant for.

Here is the [link](http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Integrate+Solr+with+Liferay+portal)

Can someone please explain what are the benefits for using the plugin (for liferay) and what it accomplishes on top of using SOLR?

Thanks

Comment: I haven't used it but I guess that's just Solr admin web app integrated into Liferay.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per this [link](http://www.liferay.com/web/guest/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Pluggable+Enterprise+Search+with+Solr) it is to externalize the search function from the portal.

Using Solr instead of Lucene gives you the additional capabilities of Solr such as Replication, Sharding, Result clustering through Carrot2, Use of custom Analyzers/Stemmers etc.

It also can offload search server processing to a separate cluster.

Opens up the possibilities of search driven UI (facetted classification etc) separate from your portal UI.